# Implementing an accordian-type view in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, conventions

In a toy application, I have a 'posts' template that shows all of the post titles. When you click each title, instead of heading to a 'show' view I want to expand down the rest of the contents of that post, directly inline.

I've considered having the `postRoute` reuse the `postsRoute` and set a flag that would then be checked against in the handlebars template to splat out the rest of the post content.

What would be a preferred 'Ember-ish' approach that would let a resource's singular view be rendered inline with its index view in the correct location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest to define an `itemController` on `PostsController` which can take actions for individual post objects.
Then, in your template define the action (e.g. toggleBody) that toggles a property on the itemController. You can use this property to show or to hide the body of each post:

```
App.PostsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend
  itemController: 'post'

App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  showBody: no
  actions:
    toggleBody: ->
      @toggleProperty('showBody')
      return false

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="posts">
<ul>
  {{#each}}
    <li>{{title}} <span {{action toggleBody}} class='label'>Toggle</span>
    {{#if showBody}}        
      <div>{{body}}</div>
    {{/if}}
    </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
</script>
```

See also [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazzel/2tCFK/) for a working demo.